# RecyclerView doesn't show any items even though getItemCount() returns the correct count in the adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

everyone. I have a RecyclerView in which I want to display items. For this I implemented an adapter class and the required functions. I have 3 identical example data sets which I pass to the adapter and which are also correctly displayed as 3 in getItemCount(). However, my problem is that I can't see anything. The RecyclerView remains empty. I also don't get any errors in the terminal/debugger, everything is correct. Have I made a mistake and perhaps forgot something?

Here is my OverviewActivity containing the RecyclerView:

```
class OverviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var resultsAdapter: ResultsAdapter
private lateinit var listResults : ArrayList<HouseModel>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview)

 listResults = ArrayList()


 var resultRv: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.result_rv)

 resultRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
 resultsAdapter = ResultsAdapter(this, listResults)
 resultRv.adapter = resultsAdapter

 //TEST DATA
 listResults.add(HouseModel("Abador",R.drawable.house,R.drawable.alle,"Bella Vista, PY","650","Schönes, neu renoviertes Haus. Mit neuestem Standard. Kann besichtigt werden"))
 listResults.add(HouseModel("Abador",R.drawable.house,R.drawable.alle,"Bella Vista, PY","650","Schönes, neu renoviertes Haus. Mit neuestem Standard. Kann besichtigt werden"))
 listResults.add(HouseModel("Abador",R.drawable.house,R.drawable.alle,"Bella Vista, PY","650","Schönes, neu renoviertes Haus. Mit neuestem Standard. Kann besichtigt werden"))

 resultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

 ... } }
```

Model class:

```
data class HouseModel(

var senderName: String,
var mainImg : Int,
var senderImg: Int,
var place: String,
var price: String,
var desc: String,
)
```

ResultsAdapter:

```
class ResultsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val resultsList: ArrayList<HouseModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ResultsAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflateView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.result_list_rv,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(inflateView)
}


class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val mainImg: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list_main_img)
    val senderImg: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_rv_sender_img)
    val senderName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_rv_sender_name)
    val place: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_rv_place)
    val desc: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_rv_desc)
    val price: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_rv_price)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ResultsAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.mainImg.setImageResource(resultsList[position].mainImg)
    holder.senderImg.setImageResource(resultsList[position].senderImg)
    holder.senderName.text = resultsList[position].senderName
    holder.place.text = resultsList[position].place
    holder.desc.text = resultsList[position].desc
    holder.price.text = resultsList[position].price
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
  println("ITEMS: ${resultsList.size}")
  // SHOWS I/System.out: ITEMS: 3
  return resultsList.size
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**

RecyclerView Code:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/result_rv"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"> 
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And my code for result_list_rv.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list_main_img"
            android:src="@drawable/longtime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_img"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/shorttime"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Abador"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baumans"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:gravity="right">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_place"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bella Vista, PY"
                    android:textSize="16sp">
               </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_price"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="600 USD/mtl"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_desc"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_message_btn"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/send"></ImageButton>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reviewed your code and I think the problem is in the  result_list_rv.xml file,
try to set the main linear layout width = match_parent and last RelativeLayout height = wrap_content

Comment: Ok cool that worked so far that I can see the rv_list_main_img ImageView. However, all other elements are not filled or are not visible